# What's the different between getHtml() and getData() of CKeditor

Tags: ckeditor

For CKeditor, there are two functions available for getting the data from the editor.

In the followinf example, there is an instance named `p_editor`, and the output of both functions is the same.

```
var p_editor=CKEDITOR.replace( 'question_editor');
$('#PostQuestion').on('click', function() { 
    console.log( p_editor.getData());
    console.log(p_editor.document.getBody().getHtml());
    console.log(p_editor.document.getBody().getText());
});
```

So I want to know what's the difference of these two functions.

Answer (score 0):

These two methods operate on different types of objects:

- `getData()` is a method of the `CKEDITOR.editor` class.
- `getHtml()` is a method of the `CKEDITOR.dom.element` class.

Your code `p_editor.document.getBody().getHtml()` gets the `body` dom element and executes the `getHtml()` method on it. In this case it's the same as `getData()` of the entire editor but you could use `getHtml()` on another dom element within the body and get its (partial) HTML.

Here's the documentation:

- [getData](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-getData)
- [getHtml](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.element-method-getHtml)